# Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Bad Request (CODE: 400)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-function-app, kudu

I am using the Devops release pipeline to deploy new releases to my function apps.

However a few days ago, the release pipeline stopped working and I continue to receive the following error message on deployments:

*Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Bad Request (CODE: 400)*

After digging in the kudu stack trace, I find the following:

*Error occurred, type: error, text: No space left on device*

However, when I look at my quota usage on the app service plan that hosts my function apps, I have not even exceeded 1% of my quota. I am on a basic app service plan that provides 10gb of storage and my function apps combined have used 50mib.

I am reaching out to see if anyone else has/is currently experiencing this issue and what they did to resolve it.

Many Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters this issue in the future this **may** resolve your problem.

I believe the problem with deployments may have been caused by a corrupt function app in the app service plan. I noticed that the function app I recently added had been categorised as a container although I never specified it as such. Anyway, deleting that function app and recreating it resolved the issue. All deployments to that app service plan are now working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Some advice for trouble shooting:

1. You can use the [Kudu service](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) to see the size of all the files on the Azure. This way you can further check your storage. Go to **Azure portal -> Your_APP_Service -> development tool -> advanced tool** to access Kudu service and download the extension. You can click [this blog](https://feng.lu/2017/02/23/Review-and-manage-your-web-site-space-in-Azure/) for detailed information.

[image]

2. The issue may be that your source code and output are too large. In this case, try using a self-hosted agent and clear the cache.
3. The reason for the issue may also be that the packages uploaded at one time are too large, which leads to the shortage of [temporary files](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#temporary-files). Click on the link to see if you have exceeded the temporary file limit.

Comment: Hi Jane, unfortunately many of these options appear to be unavailable for my app service plan because it is linux based. I'm going to try first deleting the function apps & the plan before redeploying everything again. If that works, brilliant. If not, I'll fork out for the more expensive windows based app service plan which should give me better diagnostic capabilities.

Comment: @user3918443 Redeploying should solve this question. Looking forward to hearing your good news.

Comment: @user3918443 Do you have the same error when you deploy locally?

Comment: I've resolved the issue now. I believe the problem with deployments may have been caused by a corrupt function app in the app service plan. I noticed that the function app I recently added had been categorised as a container although I never specified it as such. Anyway, deleting that function app and recreating it resolved the issue. All deployments to that app service plan are now working fine!

Comment: @user3918443 Glad to hear that you have solved your issue! You can post your solution and accept it as an answer, so that people with similar questions can benefit from it~

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I connected with ssh to app service and run:

```
$ df -h
```

[image]

and scale up (App service plan)(be careful the server IP can change)

[image]

[image]

And after run the pipeline, Its run Correctly, if you wish you can return to the previous plan.